# How to use an interface/something similar to clean up duplicate code in Java

Tags: java, oop, interface, coding-style, code-duplication

I have output functions that output data from different objects to their corresponding files. Most of these functions follow the same pattern, the only differences are the objects being used and by extension, the object's inherent methods being used.

I pass in 'obj' to all the write functions, and in each individual write function we call different 'obj.get...' functions to get different objects to grab data from to output.

My output functions are called like so:

```
for (Object obj : objects) {
    writer.writeSubOject1(obj, dir, "subObject1.csv", true);
    writer.writeSubOject2(obj, dir, subObject2.csv, true);
    ....
}
```

Code for the write functions:

```
public class Writer{

public void writeSubOject1(Object obj, File dir, String filename, Boolean append) {
    ArrayList<SubObject1> subObject1 = obj.getSubObject1();
    try {
        log.info("writing " + filename + "...");
        ArrayList<String[]> so1Data = SubObject1.getData(subObject1);
        final File out = CreateFileObject(dir, filename);
        writeCsv(so1Data, out, append);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("Error in writeSubOject1");
        log.error(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void writeSubOject2(Object obj, File dir, String filename, Boolean append) {
    ArrayList<SubObject2> subObject2 = obj.getSubObject2();
    try {
        log.info("writing " + filename + "...");
        ArrayList<String[]> so2Data = SubObject2.getData(subObject2);
        final File out = CreateFileObject(dir, filename);
        writeCsv(so2Data, out, append);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("Error in writeSubOject2");
        log.error(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

You can see that the only differences between the two methods is the **obj.getSubObjectX()** call, and the **getData()** method which has a unique implementation in SubObject1 and 2.

Is there a better way to do this to get rid of duplicate code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a private method

```
writeSubOject(ArrayList<String[]> soData, File dir, String filename, Boolean append) {
   try {
        log.info("writing " + filename + "...");
        final File out = CreateFileObject(dir, filename);
        writeCsv(soData, out, append);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("Error in writeSubOject");
        log.error(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

then in your public methods

```
public void writeSubOject1(Object obj, File dir, String filename, Boolean append) {
    ArrayList<SubObject1> subObject1 = obj.getSubObject1();
    ArrayList<String[]> so1Data = SubObject1.getData(subObject1);
    writeSubOject(so1Data,dir,filename,append);
}

public void writeSubOject2(Object obj, File dir, String filename, Boolean append) {
    ArrayList<SubObject2> subObject2 = obj.getSubObject2();
    ArrayList<String[]> so2Data = SubObject2.getData(subObject2);
    writeSubOject(so2Data,dir,filename,append);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not well put, but I will try to answer as best as I can with the provided information.

First, I would write an abstract class.

```
public abstract class WritableObject {
    List<WritableObject> children = new ArrayList<>();
    public abstract  List<String> getDataAsStringList();
    List<WritableObject> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }
    
    public void addChild(WritableObject wo) {
        children.add(wo);
    }
}
```

Now we can implement this interface in as many other classes as needed. Let's assume you have two for now.

```
    public class WritableObjectOne extends WritableObject {

    @Override
    public List<String> getDataAsStringList() {
        return Arrays.asList(""); // here the object returns it's String representation
    }
}

public class WritableObjectTwo extends WritableObject {

    @Override
    public List<String> getDataAsStringList() {
        return Arrays.asList(""); // here the object returns it's String representation
    }
}
```

Now, the best part is that you can combine however you want. You can have children of any WritableObject and can have children for the child and so on.

Now, in your writer, you can just have one method:

```
public class Writer {
    public void writeSubOject(WritableObject obj, File dir, String filename, Boolean append) {
        List<WritableObject> children = obj.getChildren();
        try {
            log.info("writing " + filename + "...");
            List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
            for (WritableObject child:children) {
                data.addAll(child.getDataAsStringList());
            }
            final File out = CreateFileObject(dir, filename);
            writeCsv(data, out, append);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("Error in writeSubOject1");
            log.error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Again, maybe this is not exactly how you want it (I find it weird how a list of strings is returned), but it should at least help you get to the right solution.